# How to populate select box with the session values in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have stored many employee objects in session. how to populate the select box with the name of the all employees.i am very new to cakephp so explain me the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your employee objects in your session are in the following format
`array('Employee.id' => 'Employee.name')` you can populate the selectbox with the following statement in your views: `$this->Form->select('employees', $employees)` (where $employees is an array formatted as above).

See also http://book.cakephp.org/view/1430/select for more info on the syntax of the select box.

Comment: You have to click the checkmark on the left of my answer to accept it, not just post a comment ;-)

Comment: Now i have to automatically fill the text boxes such as name ,age and  address of employee's name,age and address on selecting the employee name from the drop down box .explain me how to do this

Comment: You have to use javascript to do that. With the onSelect event you can make this work. You might need to make an Ajax call to get additional information like the age and address.